# Select string as number on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I found this odd behavior and I'm breaking my brains with this... anyone has any ideas?

Oracle 10g:
I have two different tables, both have this column named "**TESTCOL**" as **Varchar2(10)**, not nullable.

If I perform this query on **table1**, i get the proper results:

```
select * from table1 where TESTCOL = 1234;
```

**Note** that I'm specifically not placing '1234'... it's not a typo, that's a dynamic generated query and I will try not to change it (at least not in the near future).

But, if I run the same query, on **table2**, I get this error message:

```
ORA-01722: Invalid number
```

Both queries are run on the same session, same database.

I've been joining these two tables by that column and the join works ok, the only problem shows whenever I try to use that condition.

Any ideas on what could be different from one table to the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `TESTCOL` contains non-numbers, then Oracle might run into problems when converting `TESTCOL` entries to numbers. Because, what it does internally, is this:

```
select * from table1 where TO_NUMBER(TESTCOL) = 1234;
```

If you're so sure that `1234` cannot be expressed as a `VARCHAR` literal, then try this instead, in order to compare varchar values, rather than numeric ones:

```
select * from table1 where TESTCOL = TO_CHAR(1234);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well obvious TABLE2.TESTCOL contains values which *are not numbers*.  Comparing a string to a numeric literal generates an implicit conversion. So any value in TESTCOL hich cannot be cast  to a number will hurl ORA-1722.

It doesn't hit you  where you compare the two tables because you are comparing strings.

So you have a couple of options, neiher of which you will like.  The most obvious answer is to clean the data so TABLE2 hdoesn't contain non-numerics.  Ideally you should combine this with changing the column to a numeric data type.  Otherwise you can alter the generator so it produces code you can run against a shonky data model.  In this case that means wrapping literals in quote marks if the mapped column has a character data type.

Answer (score 4):

You are hitting the perils of implicit typecasting here.

With the expression `testcol = 1234` you state that you want to treat `testcol` as a numeric column, so Oracle tries to convert all values in that column to a number.

The ORA-01722 occurs because apparently at least one value in that column is **not** a number.

Even though you claim that this is "*not a typo*" it indeed is one. It's a syntactical error.

You will have to declare your parameter as a string literal using single quotes: `where testcol = '1234'`

Creating a correct condition is the only solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Just replace the "your where".

```
select * 
from table1 
where (select TO_NUMBER(TESTCOL) 
       from table2 
       where "your where") = 1234;
```