# Oracle - Extract numbers for comparison from varchar2 column

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

I have encountered a following problem while solving a task:

In Oracle database I have got a table `ENTITY_INFO` that is fairly simple in structure. It contains 3 columns:

`ENTITY_ID (VARCHAR2)` - PK of the entity in database

`NAME (VARCHAR2)` - name of the information, i.e. "location", "cost", "last encounter"

`VALUE (VARCHAR2)` - a value of the information, i.e. "assets/music", "1500", "1.1.2000"

Currently, I need to filter out entities that have its "cost" < 1000.

A naive approach via

`SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM ENTITY_INFO WHERE NAME = 'cost' AND TO_NUMBER(VALUE)<1000`

does not work, because column `VALUE` contains values that are not number. 
But all column values that match the filter `NAME = 'cost'` are numbers, so the case I need to do is valid.

I found [Select string as number on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890883/select-string-as-number-on-oracle) topic, but the information inside prove not useful to solving this problem.

Due to nature of `ENTITY_INFO` and a state of project, the change of datamodel is not viable solution too.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate approach leveraging `WITH` clause, on the presumption that all the records with `name` are numbers

In the tab1 part, use the filter condition and query from tab1 with `TO_NUMBER`

```
WITH tab1
     AS (SELECT entity_id, name, VALUE
           FROM entity_info
          WHERE name = 'cost')
SELECT *
  FROM tab1
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (VALUE) < 1000
```

Having numbers and characters in one column is an accident waiting to happen. Adding another column to distinguish numeric and non-numeric is not an option, I would reckon to have a constraint to deter entering non-numeric if `name` is `cost`

Answer (score 4):

You could make the conversion to a number conditional:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID
FROM ENTITY_INFO
WHERE NAME = 'cost'
AND TO_NUMBER(CASE WHEN NAME = 'cost' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END) < 1000
```

Comment: Both your and mine answer rely on the promise that values for `name='cost'` will truly be number-like strings. If they are not, both of our codes would lead to an error (`invalid number`). On the other hand, if they truly are number-like strings,then using `CASE` in this matter is redundant, both code-wise and performance-wise, as simple `VALUE < 1000` would then be sufficient. I described it in more detail in my answer and showed it with some sample data.

Comment: The issue is what happens for values related to names other than 'cost'. I'm stopping it even trying to convert those. Your second code block is also trying that, but the optimiser can cause that to still fail.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I opted for going with the "WITH - AS" way as it helped me to orient myself in the remainder of a code a bit better.

Comment: This is the right answer.  You should not depend on a CTE executing "before" the outer `WHERE`.  Oracle might decide to re-arrange the operations.

Answer (score 0):

In my compiler, I see no problem with your code (or this equivalence of it's):

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID 
  FROM ENTITY_INFO
 WHERE NAME = 'cost'
   AND VALUE < 1000
```

Example with data samples:

```
with ENTITY_INFO as (
    select 1 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, '2000' as value from dual
    union all
    select 2 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, '900' as value from dual
    union all
    select 3 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, '3000' as value from dual
    union all
    select 4 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, '2500' as value from dual
    union all
    select 5 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, '700' as value from dual
    union all
    select 6 as ENTITY_ID,  'frf' as name, '250sasd0' as value from dual
    union all
    select 7 as ENTITY_ID,  'corfrst' as name, '70fa0' as value from dual
    )
SELECT ENTITY_ID 
  FROM ENTITY_INFO
 WHERE NAME = 'cost'
   AND VALUE < 1000
```

Result:

> ENTITY_ID
>
> ```
>     2
>
>     5
> ```

Alternatively, you can use the subquery that would assure that all of the resulting column values from it would be number-like strings:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID 
  FROM (SELECT ENTITY_ID,
               VALUE
          FROM ENTITY_INFO 
         WHERE NAME = 'cost' )
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(VALUE)<1000
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: Your first query is just making the `to_number()` implicit - it's still happening. You can see that by looking at the execution plan. (If it was converting the fixed value to a string, or if you supplied a string, then ASCII comparison would get wrong results anyway.) And for the second, the optimiser can push the predicate and rewrite the query so it can still hit the original error, so it may work sometimes but not always, or reliably.

Comment: @AlexPoole I never said that either `to_char()` or `to_number()` isn't happening implicitly, one of them must happen for comparison to happen.. Isn't the same thing happening in your example, using `CASE`, when you compared varchar2 `VALUE` with number `1000`? Both of our answers rely on the promise that values for `name='cost'` will truly be number-like string. Otherwise, both mine and your example would lead into an `invalid number` error. You can try to run your code after adding `select 8 as ENTITY_ID,  'cost' as name, 'b' as value from dual` to my sample data and utilizing it

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the point I was trying to make; the OP's original code and your first (and possibly second, depending on the optimiser) code block can try to convert values where name *isn't* 'cost'; mine at least limits that attempt to when it *is* 'cost'. (If there are 'cost' values which can't be converted to numbers then it's broken anyway, I agree! The question states that all cost values are numbers though.)

Comment: @AlexPoole You were right, ASCII comparison was wrong in the first place and OP's code also worked on my example data, with my compiler. I edited my answer.